# Animate on scroll down and scroll up

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am trying to animate a group of buttons from a relative position to a fixed position on each scroll by.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <button class="button"></button>
    <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 3px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.grouped {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 31px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var scrollFlag = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var menu = $(".menu"),
        scrollTop = window.scrollTop;

    if(menu.offset().top <= (scrollTop + 50)) {
        if(scrollFlag == false) {
            $(".menu button").each(function() {
                var button = $(this);

                button.addClass("grouped");
            });

            scrollFlag = true;
        }
    } else {
        $("#intro div.menu button").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("grouped");
        });

        scrollFlag = false;
    }
});
```

As it is now the buttons just jump to the fixed position. I realise this is because they do not have set top/right values for the animation to begin from.

I tried to overcome this by getting the buttons offsets and setting them as the top and left values but this didn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to fixed menu with 2 buttons on it .. or fixed each button?? .. if you fixed each button  the fixed position will make them over each other

Comment: Yes this is what I want, for them to overlap each other. The effect would be like a bunch of things all clumping together. I intend to have a second function which opens up a menu with them all inside. Its just a cool way of having them accessible from anywhere within the page.

Answer (score 0):

What about JQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function?

You can do something like:

```
$("#myButton").animate({         
    //this value would either be how far you want it to move, 
    //or the final position; I'm not sure which.
    top: 50px; 
    left: 50px;
}, 500); //the number here is the time in ms for the animation to play.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe its how much you want it to move. But again this is relative to the container... I think, so it will have the same effect that my code has.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its good idea but anyway

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var menu = $(".menu"),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if($('.button:nth-child(1)').css('position') !== 'fixed'){
        if(menu.offset().top <= (scrollTop + 50)) {
            $(".menu button").each(function() {
                var button = $(this);

                button.addClass("grouped");
            });
        }
    } else {
        if(scrollTop  <= 31){
            $("div.menu button").each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("grouped");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e3dvpbc/3/)

Comment: Thanks, are you seeing an animation with this? It's just jumping for me the same way my code does.